# Comments on pages not appearing, even though I enabled them

Tags: comments

I disabled once comments on my pages, and I do not remember how, and now I tried to enable them and they do not appear.

I am aware to the checkbox at the bottom of the page & screen options, but nothing. I even created new page to eliminate the possibility that its a problem with my old pages, and nothing.

Anyone got an idea? 
Please let me know if I posted in the correct `StackExchange` platform. If not let me know where.

Thank you.

Comment: So am I right in saying the comment submission box does not appear at the bottom of pages that have discussion turned on?

Comment: Have you changed themes in the meantime? Did you test with a default (2015) theme?

Comment: @JasonMurray - it does appear and its enabled.... Thank you

Comment: @SaurabhShukla good idea. I`ll try to change a theme and see the impact (hope wont kill my users....

Answer (score 0):

As @SaurabhShukla mentioned in one of the comments, the problem was probably the theme.

I use Virtue. Its great and got tons of options, and in one of them, under `misc` settings (*a place which is totally unlooked-for*), sits an option/out button.

Hope this will help someone else in the future. Thank you all for trying to solve my problem.

http://themes.kadencethemes.com/virtue/

Answer (score -2):

Settings > Discussion

...

Various settings there, in particular tick: "Allow people to post comments on new articles"

Comment: These settings are overridden by the per post settings in screen options that the asker has told us is enabled.

Comment: I think you misread @JasonMurray - the user has not mentioned whether they have this setting activated. Yes they can be over-ridden, but should definitely be turned on to activate comments sitewide.

Comment: @ColinMcDermott thank you for the comment. This option was checked.

Comment: @ColinMcDermott the "checkbox at the bottom of the page and screen options" over rides the setting you are talking about Colin.